# Toplink client session

Tags: session, client, toplink

Is there any way i can access the object of one client session from another client session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have isolated your Entities to the client Session (ClassDescriptor.setIsIsolated) then the ClientSession does not actually hold any entity instances.  So unless you have caching disabled all queries against a ClientSession will return the same entity instances.

If you have isolated Entities or are actually using a UnitOfWork then you will have to get the value from the holding UnitOfWork/IsolatedClientSession.  It is not advisable to access a UnitOfWork or ClientSession concurrently with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get what you're trying to achieve but, according to [Server and Client Sessions](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/doc/1013/main/_html/sesun003.htm) from the TopLink Developer Guide, you're not supposed to share client session accross multiple threads:

> Although client sessions are thread-safe, do not use them to write across multiple threads. Multithread write operations from the same client session can result in errors and a loss of data. For more information, see ["Concurrency"](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/doc/1013/main/_html/sesun003.htm#CACCFHAG).

Could you clarify why you would need this?